# Simple example of retrieving information from the database and printing it out on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a simple example of selecting some data from mssql database and then printing it out arbitrarily into controls or however you would go about printing them to the page.  Thanks.

Comment: To many questions in one. Ask one question in each question. Do you need help with reading data from a database, or do you need help with outputting data on an ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at a simple option, Look at the example of gridview and sqldatasource where a gridview is populated with data from sql db. msdn is a good place to start.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx